# How to display comments pane

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am trying to display the comments pane in MS Word 2010 yet I can not find how?

I saw this pane enabled on a file. It docks at the bottom of MS Word window and shows all comments in the document in a list. Allows the user to filter by reviewer and click on a comment to go to that document point.

Attention: I am not talking about Reviewing Pane. This is something different.

Can someone please tell me how to display that?

Here is how it looks on screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the older pane before "annotations" became "Comments".

As far as I know, there is no user interface feature that will open it. Even if you assign a keystroke to the ViewAnnotations command, that command nowopens the modern Comments pane.

So you need to use VBA (or some such). At its simplest, the following should do the trick:

```
SubViewOldCommentsPane1()
ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneComments
End Sub
```

But previous experience suggests that you may want to do that only if
   there are any comments, and that you may need to zoom the pane to
   make it readable, so, e.g.

```
SubViewOldCommentsPane2()
If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count > 0 Then
  ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneComments
  ' set the percentage you want in here
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 200
End If
End Sub
```

or perhaps

```
SubViewOldCOmmentsPane3()
If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count > 0 Then
  ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneComments
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitBestFit
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 )
Highlight any comment ballon

Step 2)
Press Ctrl + F (Find) 
The Find Navigation pane will display the highlighted text

Step 3) 
Close the Find Navigation pane by clicking on the “X”
Now click on the Review pane and make sure the text in the comment balloon is no longer highlighted.

Step 4) 
Press Ctrl + F (Find)  again and keep the Ctrl key pressed after the Find Navigation pane is displayed.
Soon the Comments Pane will pop up at the bottom of the screen.
Release the Ctrl key.